# Gradle include native libaries in folder at specific path

Tags: gradle, gradle-eclipse

I have an eclipse setup with the following directory structure

- /native/Linux
- /native/Windows
- /native/Mac
- /build.gradle

and some subdirectories in those folders.

I need build.gradle to copy the entire layout of `/native` to 
`/org/sqlite/native` in the jar

how do I configure that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/31214360) you can find a demo. Basically what you in the build.gradle script is the following piece of code:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

jar {
    from('native') {
        into('org/sqlite/native')
    }
}
```

Comment: @MichaelDibbets, does my answer solve the problem? If so, please accept it.

Comment: Sorry, it took me this long to test it :-) but your solution works like a charm :-) you're a life saver